# Binary data vs. JSON between embedded device & asp.net web service

Tags: c, asp.net-mvc, json, web-services, cloud

I have a cloud/web service that is written in ASP.NET that will communicate with many embedded devices that I am working with.  Our embedded devices are in house, and they run a bare bones OS and the majority of our code is written in C that runs on them.

To work behind in enterprise environments and firewalls, communication happens via HTTP between the web service and the embedded devices (necessary requirement).  Now, I'm trying to decide on communication format between the two.  The top two that I can think of are:

1. **JSON**:  The web service and embedded device communicate via JSON.  This simplifies processing at the web service, as I can create a Model that matches the JSON format, and the controller can easily cast this data in to the class.  It is easily accessible for the web service, and JSON is very flexible: it is easy to add new fields and data to any message.  The downside is that JSON parsing on an embedded device seems expensive, and the amount of data (bytes) transferred can be high since you spell out every single key name and its data in the payload.
2. **Binary: Structs & Casting**: Alternatively, I imagine that I can create a well defined structure for the messages between the web service and embedded devices, passing binary data that is cast in to structures.  The benefit is that it seems relatively easy to process on both sides, especially on the embedded side where casting the memory is less expensive than processing JSON.  The downside of this is that it is less flexible.  It is more difficult to change the data, add fields post-deployment, etc.  Of course, you have to be careful with endianess also.

I was wondering if anyone has had any similar experiences in designing something like this.  Whether it is better to go with JSON or something like binary data with casting.

Comment: Interesting question, but I think this question can best be answered by yourself. Only you know what amount of traffic your device can handle. If you have time you could benchmark both and weigh out the pros and cons. Alternatively you could look into [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) (I think this can be easily reformatted back to JSON at server side, but don't have the overhead on client side). I don't have time now, but will come back at this question later this dat.